Can you get your USCF rating floor lowered?
As you get older, your chess playing skill often declines. If a chess player has been playing chess regularly and he has been at his floor for a long time and he is getting older, is there a way for him to get his floor reduced? If so, how would he do it?

I couldn't find anything on the USCF website. It may be in a members-only section, or the non-free sections of the rulebook, but yes, you can petition to have your rating floor lowered, according to this page: https://metrowestchess.org/community/knowledge/Ratings/Rating_floors_explained.html
